# problem in redirect with roles in function redirectTo

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

im facing a problem with redirectTo function with roles , in the login controller keeps telling undefined (hasRole) even i put use App\user in top of controller

````
    {
        if (Auth::user()->hasRole('admin')){
            $this->redirectTo = route('admin.index');
            return $this->redirectTo;
        }
         else{
            $this->redirectTo = route('post.index');
            return $this->redirectTo;
        }


    }```
````

Comment: what guard did you set to the default and what driver is the user provider for that guard using?

Comment: 'provider' => 'users', ,,,, its working fine the function ! but the controller keeps telling me there's an error

Comment: what driver is the `users` provider using? and where in that controller, this is you overriding the `redirectTo` method?

Comment: 'driver' => 'session', and yes im overrriding the redirectTo() method

Comment: what is the driver for the 'users' provider?

Comment: 'driver' => 'eloquent',

Comment: is `redirectTo` the only method you are overriding in that controller? and i assume what ever you set as the default guard is this guard that uses the session driver and the 'users' provider?

Comment: yes sir , only redirectTo()!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223535/discussion-between-yolo-and-lagbox).

Answer (score 0):

I would just override the `authenticated` method that lets you return any response you want:

```
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
    return redirect()->route(
        $user->hasRole('admin') ? 'admin.index' : 'post.index'
    );
}
```